# How to consume kafka messages from kafka topic for every 5 mins instead of consuming it continuously using cloud stream

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I wish to consume message from kafka topic every 5 minutes  and then process it and send it to another topic using spring cloud stream.  Any ideas how to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `PollableMessageSource` - see [the documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/3.0.6.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#spring-cloud-streams-overview-using-polled-consumers).

You MUST set the `max.poll.interval.ms` to more than its default (300000 - 5 minutes) to avoid a rebalance.